# SMS is getting sent 3 times..WHY?

Tags: android

I am creating a SMS Application to send SMS.

I am able to send SMS using the following code:

```
SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null,message ,null, null);
```

But why SMS sent 3 times????

Comment: post your complete code

Comment: Is the `message` longer than max length allowed in 1 SMS?